# Angular date filter converter, but date is always converted to UTC

Tags: angularjs

My filter:

```
.filter('emedicineDateTimeFormat', function ($filter) {
    return function (input) {
        if (input == null) { return ""; }

        var date = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss');
        return date.toUpperCase();

    };
});
```

if Input is: `2017-01-04T14:30:00`

then output is `04.01.2017 03:15:00`

and not `04.01.2017 14:15:00`

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want get 24-hours time use upper-cased H. An example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/antenko/ectzfckw/).

```
'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss'
```

Are you sure that you didn't misspell in output and expected result? 
Do you live in UTC+01:00 timezone?

By default AngularJS uses browser timezone. If you want use UTC you should pass the 3rd argument to date filter `'UTC'`. Look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/antenko/ectzfckw/1/).

Comment: Yes I am living in UTC+1 timezone. But it is funny why automatically changed?

Comment: and jsfiddle returns also 04.01.2017 15:30:00 and not 04.01.2017 14:30:00

Comment: My JSFiddle returns `04.01.2017 17:30:00` ;-) because I live in UTC+03:00.

Comment: i want it in local

Comment: From AngularJS date filter manual:
If not specified, the timezone of the browser will be used.

Comment: @senzacionale I changed my answer with your expected result `14:30` with JSFiddle example. Is it correct?

Comment: In JSFiddle I still get 04.01.2017 15:30:00. So I need to add timezone manually?

Comment: You should look this link: https://jsfiddle.net/antenko/ectzfckw/1/ 
Or write like this:
    var date = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'UTC');